# Sass not compiling

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass

I have an existing project that I'm trying to switch the CSS over to Sass but am having difficulty getting to work. I followed the tutorial [here](https://blog.gaya.ninja/articles/how-to-start-using-sass-and-compass-in-10-minutes/) and it works, but when I try to mimic it in my project, it is not working. In the command prompt I have c:\main\sub\working\compass watch ( this is where compass is watching ). In my config.rb file ( ../working/sass ) I have:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

#Folder settings
relative_assets = true      #because we're not working from the root
project_path = "c:\main\sub\working\"
css_dir = "../test"          #where the CSS will saved
sass_dir = "../sass"           #where our .scss files are

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
output_style = :expanded # After dev :compressed

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
line_comments = true

# Obviously
preferred_syntax = :scss
```

So I have test.scss in the sass folder and style.css in the test folder. Compass doesn't seem to find the changes so I'm sure I have the setting wrong, but can't figure out how to change them.

Folder Structure:

```
c:
 \main
  \sub
    \working
     \sass
        config.rb
        test.scss
     \test
        style.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated you're running `c:\main\sub\working\compass watch` you need to `cd` into the directory where the `config.rb` is and run `compass watch`

```
cd c:\main\sub\working\sass
compass watch
```